# Change the variable in a workflow from a separate workflow

Tags: applescript, automator

I have two workflows and I need to pass a value generated in one workflow to another workflow.

In my first workflow, I have an AppleScript which returns a number I want to put into a second workflow which I call from the first workflow like so:[image]

My second workflow (Create Class in iStudiez) has a variable 'Class Number' which I want to change when I call it from my first workflow with the return value of the AppleScript pictured above.

Comment: Automator hasn't stopped me from using variables with spaces. I'm new to this and I know its bad programming but it works. To your second point, all I'm asking for is if someone knows how to alter the variable from outside of the workflow its defined in. I don't need to specify what happens in the second workflow. It is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Automator and AppleScript in Automator, and you have not posted any actual code, it's difficult to give you an exact answer of what you're looking for.

There may be an easier solution but the solution I came up with was to create one script which will save a variable into a new script file (which will automatically be created on your desktop with the name of “Stored_Variable.scpt”.  The second script loads the value of the variable stored in the “Stored_Variable.scpt” file.

Simply paste the code from this first script, directly into the code which contains the variable you want to copy.  Be sure to paste the code after the code which sets the value of the variable you want copied.

```
--  Comment Out This Next Line Before
--    Placing This Code Into Your Script
--    Which Contains The Variable You Want Copied

set originalVariable to (path to desktop) -- Testing Purposes Only

-- Replace "originalVariable" with the
--   Name Of Your Actual Variable You Want To Pass
--   To The Next Script

set saveThisVariable to originalVariable
storeTheVariable()

-- The Following Code Belongs At The Very Bottom Of Your Script
on storeTheVariable()
    set storedVariabeFileLocation to (path to desktop as text) & "Stored_Variable.scpt"
    ----------------------
    script theVariable
        set saveThisVariable to saveThisVariable
    end script
    ----------------------
    store script theVariable in ¬
        file storedVariabeFileLocation with replacing
end storeTheVariable
```

---

Place this is second code inside the code of your AppleScript in which you are trying to retrieve the variable stored from the first AppleScript code

```
-- Gets The Variable Which Was Previously Stored
--   From The Other Applescript And Stores It In A
--   New Variable... getVariableNow

set getVariableNow to run loadTheVariable

-- -----------------------------------

-- Place Whatever Commands Here, That You Will Be Using
--   The New Variable... getVariableNow with

-- -----------------------------------

-- The Following Code Belongs At The Very Bottom Of Your Script
script loadTheVariable
    property storedVariabeFileLocation : (path to desktop as text) & "Stored_Variable.scpt"
    property theRetrievedVariable : missing value
    on getStoredVariable()
        set theScript to load script file storedVariabeFileLocation
        set theRetrievedVariable to saveThisVariable of (theVariable of theScript)
    end getStoredVariable
    set theRetrievedVariable to loadTheVariable's getStoredVariable()
end script
```